# ASP.NET role based security with AzMan and AD roles

Tags: asp.net, security, active-directory, roles, azman

I'm trying to evaluate AzMan for one of my ASP.NET applications but I have a strange problem. My test application expects three roles:

- User
- Owner
- Admin

I created XML Authorization store located in application's App_Data and added these role definitions. I configured my test ASP.NET application to use AuthorizationStoreRoleProvider and I added some test code wich uses Principal.IsInRole and PrincipalPermission. Everything worked well on my local computer with local accounts assigned to roles in AzMan.

Then I moved my test application to the server and a I assigned Active Directory users and Groups to AzMan's roles. Now PrincipalPermission and Principal.IsInRole don't work any more. Interesting is that if I assign builtin Everyone group into any role it works so there is some problem with AD users and groups assigned to roles. Can I use XML authorization store with AD groups and users? What else can cause such problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the security settings on your asp.net application.

It sounds like annonymous authentication is on, so your users are coming in as annonymous users, not themselves, therefore it works for the everyone group.

Comment: Security setting is correct. I have a diagnostic page where I see user name and domain of authenticated user.

Comment: Long shot: Are you missing domain prefix when assigning groups to Azman roles, so that it is trying to use local groups instead of domain groups? Also was the group assignment after the last login, if yes log out and in again.

Comment: Bingo. The AD structure is much more complex then I expected and groups and users are duplicated between two trees. I accidentaly assigned groups and users from different AD tree then I expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <roleManager enabled="true" cacheRolesInCookie="false" cookieName=".ASPXROLES" cookieTimeout="30" cookiePath="/" cookieRequireSSL="false" cookieSlidingExpiration="true" cookieProtection="All" defaultProvider="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" createPersistentCookie="false" maxCachedResults="25">
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add applicationName="/" name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"/>
        </providers>
    </roleManager>
```